# Ideal value of d in a d-ary heap for Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, shortest-path, heaps

I stumbled upon the following statement:

> By using a $ d $-ary heap with $ d = m/n $, the total times for these two types of operations may be balanced against each other, leading to a total time of $ O(m \log_{m/n} n) $ for the algorithm, an improvement over the $ O(m \log n) $ running time of binary heap versions of these algorithms whenever the number of edges is significantly larger than the number of vertices

[Applications of d-ary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap#Applications)

I don't understand why we choose to have a heap where nodes have exactly $ m/n $ children to speed up Dijkstra's algorithm. Remove min takes overall $ O(n \log_d n) $ time and  decrease takes $ O(m \log_d n) $, so total runtime is $ O(m \log_d n) $.

What I don't understand is say we have $ m=3, n=1 $, $ m/n $ gives 3, but $ O(m \log_3 n) $ is slower than $ O(m \log_4 n) $, so why not choose 4 as value of $ d $ instead? What motivates taking $ m/n $?

Thanks!

Comment: Dijkstra is *not* a greedy algorithm! [tag removed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever the number of edges is significantly larger than the number of vertices

What they probably mean is that $m \in \omega(n)$. Then, $m/n \in \omega(1)$ -- the base of the logarithm *grows* with $n$, that is the resulting sequence of values grows more slowly than with a fixed base.

For dense graphs in the sense that $m \in \Theta(n^2)$, the effect is most pronounced. For the sake of simplicity, say $m = cn^2$ for some $c \in (0,1)$. Then, $m/n = cn$ and therewith $\log_{m/n} n = \log_{cn} n \in O(1)$ -- the logarithmic factor has vanished, the algorithm has running-time in $O(m)$.

Note that all of this is discussing only the upper Landau-bound. In which way the true running-time cost is affected by this change is not per se clear, and the Wikipedia article is bold in claiming that it's an "improvement".

Comment: The vanishing log if  $m=n^{1+\epsilon}$, with $0<\epsilon<1$  is what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please note that $ m \leq n(n-1)/2 $, thus $m/n < n/2$. So the example $m=3, n=1$ does not happen.

**First**, the article clearly claims that this improvement is achieved whenever $ m $ is larger than $ n $,

> By using a $d$-ary heap with $d = m/n$, ..., an improvement over the O(m
>   log n) running time of binary heap versions of these algorithms
>   **whenever the number of edges is significantly larger than the number**
>   **of vertices**.

**Secondly**, the article claims that $d$ must create a balance between $m$ and $n$ in order to improve the running time,

> By using a $d$-ary heap with $d = m/n$, **the total times for these
>   two types of operations may be balanced against each other**...

Generally, we need $n$ `min-extract` and $m$ `decrease-key` operations. In the case of $d=2$, each of these operations takes $O(\log n)$ time. However, when you increase $d$, the `decrease-key` operation becomes faster, but `min-extract` can become slower. Because, within each `min-extract`, we also need to run `min-heapify` that depends on the number of children of the parent in each level.

In the extreme case, if you consider $ d=n $ then $m \log_n n < m \log_{m/n} n$, but the running time won't be better in practice. Because you need at most $ n $ `min-extract` operations, each includes a `min-heapify`. Therefore, you need $ n $ `min-heapify` operations, that will cost $ O(n) $ in this case (because $d=n$ and there are $n$ numbers in the next level of your tree). Thus the running time of your algorithms becomes $O(n^2)$ ($n$ times running `min-heapify`).

Answer (score 0):

Runtime of Dijkstra with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges and using a $d$-ary heap for the priority queue will be $O((nd+m)\log_d n)$:

- $O(nd\log_d n)$ from ExtractMin operations and
- $O(m\log_d n)$ from ChangePriority (strictly DecreaseKey) operations.

We want to balance $nd$ against $m$, given $m\gg n$. 
I.e. $nd=m$, or, $d=m/n$.
If we have a constant $d$, asymptotic time will lean towards $O(m)$ [$m\gg n$].

In practice you'll need to play around a little to know what value of $d$ works for you.